# Correct implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is the following implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath the technically correct best-practice way taking into account the unwrapping of optionals

```
 class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        var cell : UITableViewCell?
         // other methods here 
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell")! as UITableViewCell
        let myItem = items[indexPath.row]

        cell!.textLabel?.text = myItem.name
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = myItem.addedByUser

        return cell!
      }

    }
```

Comment: There's no reason to have an optional cell variable outside the method, just make a non-optional local variable inside the method

Comment: Tip: Create a new Xcode application with the "Master-Detail Application" template and you'll get sample code for free.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 2 `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is declared as

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String,
                      forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is declared as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
             cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You see, **No optionals!**

The code can be reduced to

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   // other methods here 
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
     let myItem = items[indexPath.row]

     cell.textLabel?.text = myItem.name
     cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myItem.addedByUser

     return cell
  }
}
```

In case of a custom table view cell the cell can be forced casted to the custom type.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

It's always a good idea to option-click on the symbol or use Quick Help to look up the exact signature.

Comment: If I try to do let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as UITableViewCell without unwrapping, the compiler suggest that I should unwrap using !, as in let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell")! as UITableViewCell Other than that, your code works!!

Comment: You don't need to unwrap anything because all relevant parameters are non optionals.

Comment: You said to use the second method that takes the index path parameter but your example is still using the wrong method

Comment: Force unwrapping with "as!" is not a good suggestion by many lint tools. What's the better way?

Comment: @Satyam Force unwrapping is not evil per se. There is more than just black and white. In this particular case force unwrapping is even recommended because it reveals a **design** error. If anything is hooked up correctly in Interface Builder the code must not crash.