# searchResults not showing correct words

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchresultscontroller

I have a searchResultsViewController in my iOS application that displays an array of data for the user to be able to search through. When I try to search a random letter, lets say P for instance it does not show any of the words containing P.

[image]
[image]

the code that I used to create this searchResults is,

```
    var array = ["Assembly", "Auto Care", "Electronic Help", "Item Delivery", "Handyman", "House Chores", "Junk Removal", "Lawn & Yard Care", "Moving", "Painting", "Pet Care", "Seasonal Work"]
var selectedItems = [String]()
var searchController = UISearchController()
var filteredArray = [String]()
var resultsController = UITableViewController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
    resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    
  let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: GREEN_Theme]
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Done"


}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    done()
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredArray = array.filter({ (array:String) -> Bool in
        if array.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) {
             return true
        } else {
        return false
        }
    })
    resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    searchController.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = true
 }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if selectedItems.contains(array[indexPath.row]) {
selectedItems.remove(at: selectedItems.firstIndex(of: array[indexPath.row])!)
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
} else {
selectedItems.append(array[indexPath.row])
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
tableView.reloadData()
print(selectedItems)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == resultsController.tableView {
        return filteredArray.count
        
    } else {
        return array.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = UITableViewCell()
cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
if selectedItems.contains(array[indexPath.row]) {
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}else{
cell.accessoryType = .none
}
return cell
}
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You aren't explaining the relationship between the two arrays.

Comment: @ElTomato doesnt the updateSearchResults show the relationship to the two?

Comment: It pretty confusing that you name both the data source array and the `filter` closure parameter `array`. And what's in the data source methods `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow`?

Comment: data source methods have been added.

Comment: It's obvious. Your cellForRowAt is totally wrong. It takes no account of the filtered array. So, since _two_ filtered array items contain P, you are showing the first _two_ items of the unfiltered `array`.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you are not even dequeuing cells! Basically _everything_ about cellForRowAt is wrong.

Comment: And – however unrelated to the issue – your way to maintain the selected rows is horrible. Use a struct as data source and add an `isSelected` struct member. In `cellForRow` set the `accessoryType` according to `isSelected`. And in `didSelect` toggle `isSelected` in the model and reload the row.

Comment: thanks for the criticism and feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to filter stuff:

```swift
extension SearchVC: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        fetchedData = []
        if searchText == ""{
            fetchedData = items
        } else {
            for words in items{
                if
                    words.item.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()){
                    filteredData.append(words)
                }
            }
        }
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Where `fetchedData` is an empty string array and `items` is your array.
If the search bar is empty `fetchedData` will be filled with all of your items, else just with the matched ones.

Now, the most important thing to do is to use `fetchedData` instead of `items` to display the results and the count properly. So, for instance:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
return filteredData.count
}
```

Furthermore, as other users pointed out in the comments, you should really check your `cellForRowAt`. Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345245/10408872